# How to Select New values in View in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

here is my method

```
public PartialViewResult GetAllClassroom()
    {
        Guid entityId = new Guid();
        var searchClassRooms = from m in db.Forms
                               where m.FormTypeEnumId == "CLASSROOM" && m.FormTitle.ToUpper() == "Add a Classroom".ToUpper() && m.EntityId == entityId
                               join fs in db.FormSubmits on m.FormId equals fs.FormId
                               select new
                               {
                                   FormId = m.FormId,
                                   FormSubmitsId = fs.FormSubmitId,
                                   FormTitle = fs.FormTitle,
                                   CreatedOn = fs.CreatedOn
                               };

        return PartialView("_getClassRoom", searchClassRooms.Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn).ToList());
    }
```

i want to pass these values in my view but it is saying no model passed to view... the view is as below

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <p>FormId: </p> @item.FormId
   <p>FormSubmitsId : </p> @item.FormSubmitsId 
   <p>FormTitle : </p> @item.FormTitle 
   <p>CreatedOn : </p> @item.CreatedOn 
}
```

what i am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your view defined with `@model IEnumarable<expectedType> or IList<expectedType>`?

Comment: Have you binded your View with a Model
?

Comment: what type did you set in your view (@model)? you are generating an anonymous type in your query.

Comment: i can't bind the List of model because i am passing new variables .. i have attached an screenshot there...

Comment: Create a view model with those 4 properties

Answer (score 1):

do the following

1- create a class Result as follows

```
public class Result
{
    public int FormId{get; set;}
    public int FormSubmitsId{get; set;}
    public string FormTitle{get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn{get; set;}
}
```

2- change the code in your controller to the following

```
public PartialViewResult GetAllClassroom()
    {
        Guid entityId = new Guid();
        var searchClassRooms = from m in db.Forms
                               where m.FormTypeEnumId == "CLASSROOM" && m.FormTitle.ToUpper() == "Add a Classroom".ToUpper() && m.EntityId == entityId
                               join fs in db.FormSubmits on m.FormId equals fs.FormId
                               select new Result // adding the Result to be strongly typed view
                               {
                                   FormId = m.FormId,
                                   FormSubmitsId = fs.FormSubmitId,
                                   FormTitle = fs.FormTitle,
                                   CreatedOn = fs.CreatedOn
                               };

        return PartialView("_getClassRoom", searchClassRooms.Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn).ToList());
    }
```

3- modify your view to the following

```
@model IEnumerable<YourSolutionName.Models.Result> // you might change the path of your Result class

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <p>FormId: </p> @item.FormId
   <p>FormSubmitsId : </p> @item.FormSubmitsId 
   <p>FormTitle : </p> @item.FormTitle 
   <p>CreatedOn : </p> @item.CreatedOn 
}
```

**EIDTED**

to keep your setting as it is which means to pass an anonymous object to the view

then you can render the view using reflection in this way

```
@model dynamic
@{
    var type = Model.GetType().GetProperties();
}
@foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type)
{
    <p>@(property.Name) :</p>@property.GetValue(Model, null)
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: i know this .. i am asking it without passing result model. as we can pass this type of query with JSON . JSON can recieve these variable just as item.FormId then how i can i do the same for Razor

Comment: How can you do it without passing MODEL??. How the View will know about which Model you are using??

Comment: there is no any solution to do it without using Model after select new because if i will do the same with JSON then JSON will recieve the values in $.each(data, function(i, item){formId=item.FormId;});

Comment: @VipsSaini i edited the answer to show you how to display the details of anonymous objects, hope it will help you

Comment: @VipsSaini does my answer helped you after editing it to display the view as dynamic at the end of my answer? if so, kindly mark it as answer